# c++\CLI dll wrapper to call virtual members in c++ class

Tags: c++, c++-cli, wrapper, labview

I'm trying to write a dll wrapper in c++/CLI to connect functions in my native c++ class to be used in LabView. I've successfully written a wrapper that does this and everything works as expected (see below). The Problem is explained at the bottom (after Labview image).

Native c++ header file.

```
//native c++ header
#pragma once

namespace AddTwoNumbersLib
{
class AddClass
{
private:
    double _x;
    double _y;
    bool _test;

public:
    //Constructor
    AddClass();

    //Member functions
    virtual bool toggle (bool test);
    double Add(double x, double y);
    static double subtract(double z, double a);
};
}
```

Native c++ .cpp file.

```
// native c++ .cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "AddClass.h"

namespace AddTwoNumbersLib
{
//Constructor
AddClass::AddClass()
{}

//Member functions
double AddClass::Add(double x, double y)
{
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
    return _x + _y;
}

double AddClass::subtract(double z, double a) 
{
    return z - a;
}

bool AddClass::toggle(bool test)
{
    _test = test;
    return _test;
}
}
```

Wrapper c++/CLi header file.

```
// ClrWrapper.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace ClrWrapper {

public ref class MathWrap
{
private:
    AddTwoNumbersLib::AddClass *_MyManagedAdd;
    AddTwoNumbersLib::AddClass *_push;

public:
    //Constructs an instance of the class and an
    //instance of the underliying native class AddClass
    MathWrap();
    ~MathWrap();

    double AddWrapper(double x, double y);
    double subWrap(double z, double a);
    bool toggleWrap(bool push);
};
}
```

Wrapper c++/CLI .cpp file

```
// This is the main DLL file.

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "ClrWrapper.h"

using namespace ClrWrapper;

MathWrap::MathWrap()
{
_MyManagedAdd = new AddTwoNumbersLib::AddClass();
_push = new AddTwoNumbersLib::AddClass();
}

MathWrap::~MathWrap()
{
delete _MyManagedAdd;
}

double MathWrap::AddWrapper(double x, double y)
{
return _MyManagedAdd->Add(x, y);
//return AddTwoNumbersLib::AddClass::Add(x, y);
}

double MathWrap::subWrap(double z, double a)
{
return AddTwoNumbersLib::AddClass::subtract(z, a);
}

bool MathWrap::toggleWrap(bool push)
{
return _push->toggle(push);
}
```

LabView results:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3420.jpg)

**The Problem**

when I change the header file to a a pure virtual My code no longer works. It's because I'm trying to instantiate (from a now abstract class) in the wrapper .cpp. I would really appreciate some help in a work around for this problem.

```
virtual bool toggle (bool test) = 0;
```

Comment: In which class do you implement the virtual function?

Comment: It's declared/implemented in the native c++. It's the AddClass

Comment: You said you declared it pure-virtual.

Comment: Correct, I originally declared it as virtual, and it worked fine. Once I made it pure virtual the code broke.

Comment: Because you didn't implement the pure virtual method anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The Pointer to the native class `AddClass` may be a pointer to a pure virtual class/interface, or may contain functions that are pure virtual.
2. The class you create with new (derived from `AddClass`), must have all functions implemented!
3. So you have the chance to use different derived classes from `AddClass` with different behaviours. But each derived class must have all virtual functions implemented!

This doesn't matter if you have C++ or C++/CLI.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll give it another try today. I'm a little confused when you say the class created with new, as new just creates an instance of the Add class.

Comment: You must create the derived class! You can't create the AddClass as long as it has pure virtual members.